# what does the keyword this refer to in a default method of an interface in java?

Tags: java

I tested the following programms and the result is weird to me where I think it should be A.

```
interface O{
   default O get(){
      return this;
   }
}


class A implements O{
   public O get(){
     return O.super.get();
   }
}


 class B extends A{
    public O get(){
       return super.get();
    } 
 }


new B().get().getClass().getName() == B
```

Comment: Same thing it means everywhere else in Java.

Comment: You have created only one object. There is nothing surprising in fact that `this` references on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder how you run this syntactically wrong code?

But to answer your question, `this` is just a reference to an object, and the actual class of an object does not change just because you return `this` from a super class. If the object is `B` (and not something derived from B), then `this.getClass()` will always be `B.class`.

PS: Please don't compare strings with `==`.

Comment: So a method that has statments like `getDeclaredFields()` cannot be inherited effectively?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this. You can always call `A.class.getDeclaredFields()` instead of `getClass().getDeclaredFields()`  to get the fields declared in class `A`.

Answer (score 1):

**This** means "Intance of the class that implements this interface." in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Default methods of interface can refer to the instance of a class that implements the interface using **this** keyword:

```
package test;
public class ThisInterface {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           A1 c1 = new C1();
           A1 c2 = new C2();
           c1.printCurrentClassName();
           c2.printCurrentClassName();
    }
}

interface A1 {
    default void printCurrentClassName() {
        System.out.println("Current Class Name  = " + this.getClass().getName());
    }
}

class C1 implements A1 {}
class C2 implements A1 {}
```

the code prints:

```
Current Class Name  = test.C1
Current Class Name  = test.C2
```